# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined How to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var item_data = [];
var index = 0;
var data = JSON.parse([{"A":"0","B":"100","C":"0","D":"0"}]);
item_data[index].push(data);
console.log(item_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone can please help me why it appearing script error in my system it appearing

> Uncaught TypeError: item_data[index].push is not a function

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: item_data.push not item_data[index].push

Comment: Parsing an already "parsed" object is not ok!

Comment: use `item_data.splice(index, 0, data);`  to insert at  a specific position

Answer (score 1):

Use assignment operator (`=`) to insert any item at specific position of an array by using index like:

`item_data[index] = data;`

**OR:** If you want to use [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) you do not need to use index at all. Because

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

`item_data.push(data);`

```js
var item_data = [];
var index = 0;
var data = JSON.parse('[{"A":"0","B":"100","C":"0","D":"0"}]');
item_data[index] = data;
console.log(item_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the JSON to string and push that into the array `item_data`.

```js
var item_data = [];
var index = 0;
var data = JSON.stringify([{"A":"0","B":"100","C":"0","D":"0"}]);
item_data.push(data);
console.log(item_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```